# Passing a value from inputField to NSTextField

Tags: macos, swift4, nstextfield

I'd like to pass string value from one `NSTextField` to another `NSTextField` pressing a button. I used for this `for-in loop`. I need to pass a value from `inputField` to `visibleText1`, then to `visibleText2` and then to `visibleText3`. But it doesn't work.

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var visibleText1: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var visibleText2: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var visibleText3: NSTextField!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) { }
    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) { }

    @IBAction func applyButton(sender: AnyObject) {      
        for u in (visibleText1.stringValue...visibleText3.stringValue) {
            visibleText.stringValue[u] = inputField.stringValue
            inputField.stringValue = ""
        }
    }
}
```

Xcode gives me an error:

```
// Type 'ClosedInterval<String>' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'
```

**How how to do it right?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't do that because you can't create a range of string values of different text fields.

You could make an array of the three fields and enumerate that:

```
@IBAction func applyButton(sender: AnyObject) {      
    for field in [visibleText1, visibleText2, visibleText3] {
        field.stringValue = inputField.stringValue
    }
    inputField.stringValue = ""
}
```

or with the `forEach` function

```
@IBAction func applyButton(sender: AnyObject) {      
    [visibleText1, visibleText2, visibleText3].forEach {
        $0.stringValue = inputField.stringValue
    }
    inputField.stringValue = ""
}
```

Resetting the `inputField` in the repeat loop would always apply an empty string after the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with this, but I will start with what *will* work:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var visibleText1: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var visibleText2: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var visibleText3: NSTextField!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) { }
    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) { }

    @IBAction func applyButton(sender: AnyObject) {      
        for u in [visibleText1, visibleText2, visibleText3] {
            u.stringValue = inputField.stringValue
        }
    }
}
```

So what's wrong with the original?

1) Your `(visibleText1.stringValue...visibleText3.stringValue)` is of type `String ... String`, which is not what you intended. You need to have an array of `NSTextField`s.

2) `visibleText.stringValue[u]` is not even a thing. There is no variable `visibleString`, and even if it was an `NSTextField` - which I think is what you want it to be, it's `.stringValue` is a `String`, and not an array.

3) What are you doing setting `inputField.stringValue = ""` inside the for loop? If your construct worked, only the first field would be set.

4) Not an error, but why are you doing all of this inside `NSApplicationDelegate`, rather than a viewController?